# Tensorflow Eager execution won't work

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been trying to replicate the [Eager Execution tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/eager) using the MNIST dataset, but it doesn't work... I get no error, but it looks like as the code just stops in the first round, the output is
`Epoch 000: Loss: nan, Accuracy: 9.898%`
I've tested other MNIST codes and they progressed faster... (I waited for about 30 min)

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()


#Load dataset
mnist = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset('mnist')
train_data = mnist.train.images 
train_labels = np.asarray(mnist.train.labels, dtype = np.int32)
test_data = mnist.test.images 
test_labels = np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, dtype = np.int32)


train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data, train_labels))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100000)
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(10)

features, label = iter(train_dataset).next()
print("example features:", features[0])
print("example label:", label[0])

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="relu", input_shape=(784,)),  # input shape required
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="relu"),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)
])


def loss(model, x, y):
    y_ = model(x)
    return tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=y, logits=y_)

def grad(model, inputs, targets):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss_value = loss(model, inputs, targets)
    return tape.gradient(loss_value, model.variables)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.01)


train_loss_results = []
train_accuracy_results = []

num_epochs = 200

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    epoch_loss_avg = tf.contrib.eager.metrics.Mean()
    epoch_accuracy = tf.contrib.eager.metrics.Accuracy()

    for x,y in train_dataset:
        grads = grad(model, x, y)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.variables),
                                  global_step=tf.train.get_or_create_global_step())

        epoch_loss_avg(loss(model, x, y))

        epoch_accuracy(tf.argmax(model(x), axis=1, output_type=tf.int32), y)

    train_loss_results.append(epoch_loss_avg.result())
    train_accuracy_results.append(epoch_accuracy.result())

    if epoch % 50 == 0:
        print("Epoch {:03d}: Loss: {:.3f}, Accuracy: {:.3%}".format(epoch,
                                                                epoch_loss_avg.result(),
                                                                epoch_accuracy.result()))
```

PS. I know that the model probably won't be efficient, is just a test run

Comment: There seems to be a few differences between the tutorial and your code, could you point out all the differences.   'tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="relu", input_shape=(784,)),  # input shape required' appears different and maybe the input shape is off

Comment: the input shape, the batch_size, the buffer_size... the input is 28*28=784, just as the train_data format, should it be different?

Comment: Are you running code slightly different from the snippet posted above? I ask because `model` there ends with a `Dense(3)` layer. So, the shape of `y_` (which will be (10, 3)) and `y` (which will be (10)) in the `loss()` function won't match. Indeed, just running the snippet above I get an exception of the form `InvalidArgumentError: Received a label value of 9 which is outside the valid range of [0, 3)` from the call to `tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy`.

So I suspect that perhaps the code you're running is slightly different. Perhaps you want to update it?